# Как передать данные из одного представления в другое, не используя при этом контроллер?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, linq

Добрый день! У меня есть два представления. 1 отображает таблицу, при нажатии на строку таблицы открывается второе представление, необходимо из 1 представления получить данные и отобразить во втором представлении без использования контроллера. ViewBag не помогает. Как это можно сделать? и как потом сделать так чтобы при клике на текст во втором представлении открывалось 3 представление?

Comment: >без использования контроллера

зачем, позвольте полюбопытствовать?

Comment: у меня есть базовый контроллер созданный не мной который я не могу изменять. а есть унаследованный от него контроллер, который я могу изменять. в контроллере который я могу изменять есть переопределенный метод действие ActionResult Default, и здесь напрямую во View я не могу ничего передать, потому что Default в качестве параметра может принимать только один аргумент, поэтому мне и нужно как то это сделать без изменения контроллера

        public override ActionResult Default(int? page)
        {
            return base.Default(page);
        }

Comment: "без использования" и "без изменения" это немного разные вещи, не находитет?

Comment: ну да я знаю, что разные и все же как это можно сделать?

Comment: а что вам мешает пользоваться просто пользоваться своими контроллерами, не изменяя их? Ваша пролетарская гордость или более существенные причины? По-моему для получения данных из Action'а совсем не обязательно менять контроллер

Comment: Более существенные причины. Так как тогда получить данные?

Comment: ну так и используйте контроллер, какие проблемы? C помощью JS+AJAX обращайтесь с клиента на сервер и вовзращайте обратно нужное вам View, которое можно отображать хоть внутри имеющегося, хоть вместо имеющегося, хоть вперемешку с имеющимся

Answer (score 1):

1. [Session](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178581(VS.100).aspx)
2. [ViewState](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.web.ui.control.viewstate.aspx)
3. [HttpCookie](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178194.aspx)

касательно второго вопроса - повесьте на клик `@Url.Action("Index", "Controller3" ...)`

Comment: А пример можно какой-нибудь, про ViewState или HttpCookie? Так как не особо понятно из приведенных ссылок на msdn как мне потом во view получить данные другой view, которые сохраняются в тех же куки или во ViewState.